# JSoup HTML Parse and Write Results to CSV In Order

Tags: java, csv, jsoup

I am trying to find the best approach to saving the data I have parsed out of the HTML document when Jsoup into a CSV. The problem I'm having is using [CSVWriter][1] - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv/4.6 and writing the data with it. Please see my code snippet below. The structure of the data looks like the following with infobox being the main listing record with each subsequent field within it. The CSVWriter looks like it is a String Array but having trouble going from elements to write to the CSVData writer with a String Array.

The Jsoup selector is returning an array of items from the selection. For instance, when I make the selection for the name, it is returning all 9 names if there are 9 records on the page. I need to put this data together in order for each row to print into a CSV.

InfoBox >
 Name|
 Email|
 Phone|
 Website

The problem I'm having is how I'm trying to write the data on this line below

```
writer.writeAll((Iterable<String[]>) infoArray);
```

This is not working correctly and errors but wanted to show what I am kind of after and if there is somebody who's familiar with writing data from Jsoup Elements into CSV. Thanks

```
String filePath ="c:/results.csv";
                // first create file object for file placed at location
                // specified by filepath
                File file = new File(filePath);
                try {
                    // create FileWriter object with file as parameter
                    FileWriter outputfile = new FileWriter(file);

                    // create CSVWriter object filewriter object as parameter
                    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(outputfile);

                    String[] header = { "Name", "Phone", "Street","State","City","Zipcode" };
                    Elements infobox = doc.select(".info");
                    List<String> infoArray = new ArrayList<>();

                    for(int i = 0; i < infobox.size(); i++){

                        infobox.get(i).select(".business-name > span");

                        infoArray.add(infobox.get(i).select(".business-name > span").text());
                        infoArray.add(infobox.get(i).select(".phones.phone.primary").text());
                        infoArray.add(infobox.get(i).select(".street-address").text());
                        infoArray.add(infobox.get(i).select(".state").text());
                        infoArray.add(infobox.get(i).select(".city").text());
                        infoArray.add(infobox.get(i).select(".zip").text());


                    }


                    writer.writeNext(header);
                    //How to write data in order to match each record accordingly?
                    //Data should be written to CSV like the following example under each header into each corrosponding row
                    //name, phone, street
                    writer.writeAll((Iterable<String[]>) infoArray);
                    for(String ia : infoArray){


                    }

                    // closing writer connection
                    writer.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: 1. Can you please add an example of the data that jsoup returns, the expected output and the actuaql output? It will help others to understand your problem and help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what ended up working for me. The problem was not adding Strings into a String array to pass to CSVWriter. Here is my example.

```
   try {


                    String[] header = { "Name", "Phone", "Street","State","City","Zipcode" };
                    Elements infobox = doc.select(".info");

                    if(count == 0){

                        writer.writeNext(header);
                    }

                    for(int i = 0; i < infobox.size(); i++){



                        infobox.get(i).select(".business-name > span");

                        String businessName = infobox.get(i).select(".business-name > span").text();
                        String phone = infobox.get(i).select(".phones.phone.primary").text();
                        String address = infobox.get(i).select(".street-address").text();
                        //Address seems to be displayed another way too
                        String address2 = infobox.get(i).select(".adr").text();
                        //Use regular expression to normalize data


                        String[] columns = new String[]{
                                businessName, phone, address
                        };

                        writer.writeNext(columns);


                    }

                    writer.close();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is little example how to use OpenCSV. Maybe will be helpful for you.

HeaderNames.java

```java
public class HeaderNames
{

    public static final String NAME = "Name";
    public static final String PHONE = "Phone";
    public static final String STREET = "Street";
    public static final String STATE = "State";
    public static final String CITY = "City";
    public static final String ZIPCODE = "Zipcode";
}
```

DemoDTO.java

```java
import java.io.Serializable;
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvBindByName;


public class DemoDTO implements Serializable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @CsvBindByName(column = HeaderNames.NAME)
    private String name;

    @CsvBindByName(column = HeaderNames.PHONE)
    private String phone;

    @CsvBindByName(column = HeaderNames.STREET)
    private String street;

    @CsvBindByName(column = HeaderNames.STATE)
    private String state;

    @CsvBindByName(column = HeaderNames.CITY)
    private String city;

    @CsvBindByName(column = HeaderNames.ZIPCODE)
    private String zipcode;

    public String getName()
    {

    return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name)
    {

    this.name = name;
    }


    public String getPhone()
    {

    return phone;
    }


    public void setPhone(String phone)
    {

    this.phone = phone;
    }


    public String getStreet()
    {

    return street;
    }


    public void setStreet(String street)
    {

    this.street = street;
    }


    public String getState()
    {

    return state;
    }


    public void setState(String state)
    {

    this.state = state;
    }


    public String getCity()
    {

    return city;
    }


    public void setCity(String city)
    {

    this.city = city;
    }


    public String getZipcode()
    {

    return zipcode;
    }


    public void setZipcode(String zipcode)
    {

    this.zipcode = zipcode;
    }

}
```

Main.java

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;
import com.opencsv.bean.HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy;
import com.opencsv.bean.StatefulBeanToCsv;
import com.opencsv.bean.StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder;
import com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvDataTypeMismatchException;
import com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException;


public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, CsvDataTypeMismatchException, CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException
    {

    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "results.csv");

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

    List<DemoDTO> beans = new ArrayList<DemoDTO>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        DemoDTO demoDTO = new DemoDTO();

        demoDTO.setCity("city " + i);
        demoDTO.setName("name " + i);
        demoDTO.setPhone("phone " + i);
        demoDTO.setState("state " + i);
        demoDTO.setStreet("street " + i);
        demoDTO.setZipcode("zipcode " + i);

        beans.add(demoDTO);
    }

    HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<DemoDTO> strategy = new HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<>();
    strategy.setType(DemoDTO.class);

    StatefulBeanToCsv<DemoDTO> beanToCsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<DemoDTO>(writer)
        .withSeparator(';')
        .withEscapechar(CSVWriter.NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER)
        .withLineEnd(CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END)
        .withQuotechar(CSVWriter.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
        .withMappingStrategy(strategy)
        .withThrowExceptions(true)
        .build();

    beanToCsv.write(beans);

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    }

}
```